# Object variable or With block not set for SaveAs - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I get the error message "Object variable or With block not set" for the following part of code `.SaveAs Filename:="TABLE" & MyCell.Value & TeamS & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

```
Sub BreakInTables()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbs As Worksheet

Dim Found As Range, SearchRange As Range, MyCell As Range, LRow As Long, DynamicRange As Range, KitRow As Range, HoursCol As Range
Dim uniqueCell As Range, AddRow As Range, uniqueValues As Range, initialRange As Range, Team As Range, TeamS As String

Set Found = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find("TABLES", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set KitRow = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find("Costruzione kit", LookIn:=xlValues)

LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set SearchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LRow, Found.Column))

Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Cells
LastColumn = ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

Cells(Found.Row, LastColumn + 1) = "DIFFERENCE IN ACTUAL VS BUDGETED IN MIN"
Cells(Found.Row, LastColumn + 2) = "BONUS PER MIN 1 LEVA"

SearchRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copyToRange:=Range("XX1"), unique:=True
uniqueCount = Application.Count(Range("XX:XX"))
Set uniqueValues = ws.Cells([XX2], Cells(uniqueCount, "XX"))
Range("XX:XX").ClearContents

If IsNumeric(Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column).Value) = True Then
Set initialRange = ws.Range(Cells(1, "A").Address, Cells(Found.Row, KitRow.Column).Address)
Set HoursCol = ws.Range(Cells(1, LastColumn - 2).Address, Cells(Found.Row, LastColumn).Address)
Else
Set initialRange = ws.Range(Cells(1, "A").Address, Cells(Found.Row + 1, KitRow.Column).Address)
Set HoursCol = ws.Range(Cells(1, LastColumn - 2).Address, Cells(Found.Row + 1, LastColumn).Address)
End If

Set DynamicRange = initialRange

For i = 1 To 3
If i = 1 Then
    Set Team = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find("Time to change group", LookIn:=xlValues)
    TeamS = "GROUP"
    If Team Is Nothing Then GoTo NextIteration
ElseIf i = 2 Then
    Set Team = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find("Time to make KIT", LookIn:=xlValues)
    TeamS = "KIT"
    If Team Is Nothing Then GoTo NextIteration
Else
    Set Team = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find("Time to make pack", LookIn:=xlValues)
    TeamS = "PACK"
    If Team Is Nothing Then GoTo NextIteration
End If
For j = Application.Min(uniqueValues) To Application.Max(uniqueValues)
    For Each MyCell In SearchRange
        If MyCell = j Then
            Set AddRow = ws.Range(Cells(MyCell.Row, 0), Cells(MyCell.Row, LastColumn))
            Set DynamicRange = Union(DynamicRange, AddRow)
        End If
    Next MyCell
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    With wb
        .SaveAs Filename:="TABLE" & MyCell.Value & TeamS & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End With
    wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = DynamicRange
    Set DynamicRange = initialRange

Next j
NextIteration:
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is TeamS here?

Comment: I don't see where you set `SearchRange`.  After the `Dim` statement you start using it, but do not define what that range is before using it.

Comment: You are right, sorry. It's about a long module so I wrote only a part of it in the question. TeamS is a String an SearchRange is a Range.

Comment: After your statement of `Dim SearchRange as Range` I would expect to see `Set SearchRange = Range("A1:B50")` for example.  Not before.  If you are not including relevant information, it is hard to diagnose.  One way to solve your problem is to use F8 to step thru and look at those values before you get to that line or set the debugger to stop before that line and look at the value of those variables.

Comment: @DarrellH I updated my question by adding the SearchRange initialization.

Comment: You still haven't said what those values are, but as a note, in the line where you set `SearchRange` you need to precede `Cells` with `ws.`, i.e., `ws.Range(ws.Cells.....`  There is no need to add `.Address` to set the range.

Comment: @DarrellH In my worksheet there is a column "Tables". I have also created the DynamicRange which at the beginning contains the header of my data. For each distinct value of "tables" column (which is SearchRange) I want to add to DynamicRange the data of MyCells row and then I want to create a new workbook and paste there the DynamicRange I created above. Hope it is clear to you...

Comment: We are looking to solve the error you have.  What is the value of `MyCell`?  If it is `nothing` then you will get the error shown at the top.  You need to debug and follow the value of `MyCell` as your program executes.

Comment: Why don't we start over here by posting *the actual code that is failing*. Your last edit introduced some of the "missing code", but based on what is currently in the question, this should be failing long before the called out line.

Comment: @DarrellH I posted the full code above.

Comment: @Comintern You're right. I posted the full code. I am new to vba so I am sure that it has many mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

You're referring to `MyCell` as if it's a VBA variable.  (Well, partly.)

- If it ***is*** a **[variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/declaring-variables)**, them you should not use `.Value`.  (That's for worksheet cells, and even then, is rarely needed.)
- I'm assuming `MyCell` is actually a **[Named Range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)**. If so, and if it's referring to a **single cell**, you can use it like this:

`.SaveAs "TABLE" & Range("MyCell") & c & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Note that you also don't need the filename/fileformat tags since those are the function's first two parameters anyway.

As mentioned you also don't need `.Value` either since that's what a cell (or equivalent) returns by default anyhow.

Comment: MyCell is not a Named Range. I use it in for clause so as to search through all cells in SearchRange. You think it should not be a Range?

Comment: Is it a Named Range referring to a **single cell**?  If so, that's fine, you ca use the corrected syntax above